# Python - call several commands in subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, process

I need to create a subprocess in my program, but not only for one command.

My idea is to write something like this (the code is probably not correct, it's just an idea):

---

#### Example:

```
def f1(subp):
    subp.call("echo 1")
    print(subp.pid)

def f2(subp):
    subp.call("echo 2")
    print(subp.pid)

def main():
    p = Popen("", env=os.environ)
    f1(p)
    f2(p)
```

---

#### Output:

```
1
2487
2
2487
```

The point is, that PID is still the same.

---

Is it possible to "hold" the process handler and use it repeatedly for different commands? I want it mainly because of some environment variables which are set in different methods.

I prefer Python3.x, but the version doesn't matter so much to me.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't stop a process from terminating, so you can't then use the same process to run something entirely different. But it is possible to give POpen a (modified) environment, so it sohuld be easy to make something that can do the env setup once and then reuse that for each subprocess you need to use. Can you give some details on exactly what you're trying to do/achieve?